# Exibir div ao clicar em outra, varias com javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola pessoal preciso exibir um texto que esta em determinada div em uma listagem que fiz o problema que a div e a class tem o mesmo nome, por exemplo abaixo.

```html
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
```

Comment: Pela semântica, o ID de uma tag sempre deve ser único. As classes podem se repetir. Se não for assim não será possível você saber em qual tag está sendo exibido os textos.

Comment: e se a id for diferente? como faria?

Comment: teria que passar o id correto?

Comment: Se o id for diferente, exemplo: `<div id="faq1">...</div><div id="faq2">...</div>` você poderia utilizar um `JQuery` *selector* normalmente: `$("#faq1").html()`.

Comment: como faria isso amigo?

Comment: Como faria o que? Eu coloquei no exemplo: `$("#faq1").html()`. Nesse caso se você der um `console.log($("#faq1").html());` seu retorno será: `<div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text">Teste de mensagem todos</div>` não é justamente isso que você deseja?

Comment: Alterei o codigo acima acho q ue agora vc ria entender por exemplo a div ela esta style="display:none;" não mostrar e quero ao clicar no faq ela mostre aquele texto que esta escondido.

Comment: Resolvi ja obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Veja um exemplo com JavaScript puro e sem precisar usar `ID`.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

x[0].style.display = "block"; // onde 0 é o índice.

x[1].style.display = "block"; // onde 1 é o índice.
x[1].style.color = "red"; // onde 1 é o índice.

x[2].style.display = "block"; // onde 2 é o índice.
x[2].style.color = "blue"; // onde 2 é o índice.
```

```html
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
<div class="item" id="faq">
                      <div class="title"><b>Ola titulo todos</b></div>
                      <div class="text" style="display:none;">Teste de mensagem todos</div>
                
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo essa resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma.
peguei o valor do id com click e no mesmo lugar que pego ja faço a alteração da div deseja para mostrar ela.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function passar(id){ 

var display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
 if(display == "block")
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
else
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';

}; 

</script>
```

```html
<?php
$id_log_ass=$_REQUEST['id_log_ass'];


include_once("../config.inc");

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ass_mensag where men_id_ass= 0 or men_id_ass=$id_log_ass order by men_data desc");
$num_rows_men = mysql_num_rows($consulta );


while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
{
?>


<div class="item">

                      <div class="title" onclick="passar(<?php echo $linha['id_men'];?>);" ><b><?php echo $linha['men_titulo'];?></b></div>
                      <div class="text" id="<?php echo $linha['id_men'];?>"><?php echo $linha['men_mensagem'];?></div>
                
</div>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```